# Having trouble receiving input from server for simple client/server

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple client/server I'm working on. I have to send the a cookie from the server to the client(it's just a string), but my client won't read the inputStream.

Server:

```
 out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream()); 

 out.println(text);
 out.println(temp2State);
 out.println(temp2State);
```

Client:

```
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())); 

 String textClient = in.readLine();
 String temp1= in.readLine();
 String temp2= in.readLine();
```

This is just the code that seems to be giving me trouble. On the client I receive textClient but then the next 2 are blank. If I do a print out of temp2state on the server before it's sent I get a string, yet if I print out temp1 on the client, its empty. So it's seems to be lost in translation. That being said if use a for loop to receive the data(which was shown in class) it will return temp1 but then textClient is empty. This is being done on a socket so I do have try/catch but it didn't seem relevant.

Alternate input read:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            fromServer = in.readLine();
            if (fromServer != null) {
                 String textClient = in.readLine();
                 String temp1= in.readLine();
                 String temp2= in.readLine();

             }}
```

FOUND THE ISSUE:

Turns out I had a string trying to be sent with System.lineSeperator() attached which was sending an empty line.

Comment: Did you remember to use `out.flush()` and `out.close()` once you finished the print statements?

Comment: Ya I have .close() on both, and I tried flush on both of them but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you flush() before close()?

Answer (score 0):

As per Java API,
`public PrintStream(OutputStream out)` constructor Creates a new print stream and it will not flush automatically.

Please try the with constructor which accepts true to auto flush, whenever data is written in it.

Please modify your code like

```
out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. As of a few hours ago, I figured out it was actually an issue that I was returning a string + System.lineSeperator() which was returning empty.